# Script to implement advanced registry key permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

Is it possible to add advanced registry key permissions via a script?

ie:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy
```

MpsSvc – Query Value, Set Value, Create SubKey, Enumerate SubKeys, Notify, Delete, Read Control

Comment: `Get-Acl -Path HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Defaults\FirewallPolicy| select -exp access | Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -eq "NT SERVICE\MpsSvc"}| Format-List` seems to be pretty clear; however, `Set-Alc` would be [more complicated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.powershell.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Powershell script](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315270.aspx), some examples:

Listing all subkeys:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Path hkcu:\


   Hive: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER

SKC  VC Name                           Property
---  -- ----                           --------
  2   0 AppEvents                      {}
  7  33 Console                        {ColorTable00, ColorTable01, ColorTab...
 25   1 Control Panel                  {Opened}
  0   5 Environment                    {APR_ICONV_PATH, INCLUDE, LIB, TEMP...}
  1   7 Identities                     {Last Username, Last User ...
  4   0 Keyboard Layout                {}
...
```

Create a key (2 ways):

```
PS> New-Item -Path hkcu:\software\_DeleteMe
PS> New-Item -Path Registry::HKCU\_DeleteMe
```

Delete a key:

```
PS> Remove-Item -Path hkcu:\Software\_DeleteMe
PS> Remove-Item -Path 'hkcu:\key with spaces in the name'
```